# Spring Boot Order of Execution - EnvironmentPostProcessor and JPA

Tags: java, spring-boot, h2

In my Spring Boot application, I have `EnvironmentPostProcessor` to query the table (H2 database) and load data in Spring environment. I observe that `EnvironmentPostProcessor` is running before Hibernate create the tables. Hence in `EnvironmentPostProcessor`, 'No such table exist' error should come. However I do not see any of such errors and I see the data which is loaded in previous server instance. To be more clear, below are steps I am doing -

1. Start the server (Hibernate created and loaded tables in H2)
2. Update the data in table
3. Stop the server
4. Start the server - Here `EnvironmentPostProcessor` is displaying the updated data from 2nd step.

As of my learning, On server shutdown H2 schema will be destroyed. But how the data from previous run is available in `EnvironmentPostProcessor` ? Please correct me if my understanding is incorrect.

I see below hibernate specific settings in application.properties:

```
    spring.jpa.show-sql=true 
    spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.format_sql=true
spring.jpa.hibernate.naming.implicitstrategy=org.hibernate.boot.model.naming.ImplicitNamingStrategyLegacyJpaImpl 
    spring.jpa.hibernate.naming.physicalstrategy=org.hibernate.boot.model.naming.PhysicalNamingStrategyStandardImpl
```

Thanks!

Comment: Destruction of the H2 database depends on if you are using an in-memory one or not.

Comment: Yes I am using in-memory database.

Comment: Judging by what you are describing you aren't. Add some configuration to your post.

Comment: I see below hibernate specific settings in application.properties:


spring.jpa.show-sql=true

spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.format_sql=true

spring.jpa.hibernate.naming.implicit-strategy=org.hibernate.boot.model.naming.ImplicitNamingStrategyLegacyJpaImpl

spring.jpa.hibernate.naming.physical-strategy=org.hibernate.boot.model.naming.PhysicalNamingStrategyStandardImpl

Comment: Don't add additional information in comments, instead edit your question and use proper formatting.